# SQL query like GROUP BY with OR condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, recursion

I'll try to describe the real situation. In our company we have a reservation system with a table, let's call it *Customers*, where e-mail and phone contacts are saved with each incoming order - that's the part of a system I can't change. I'm facing the problem how to get count of *unique* customers. With the *unique* customer I mean group of people who has either the same e-mail or same phone number.

*Example 1*: From the real life you can imagine Tom and Sandra who are married. Tom, who ordered 4 products, filled in our reservation system 3 different e-mail addresses and 2 different phone numbers when one of them shares with Sandra (as a homephone) so I can presume they are connected somehow. Sandra except this shared phone number filled also her private one and for both orders she used only one e-mail address. For me this means to count *all* of the following rows as one *unique customer*. So in fact this *unique customer* may grow up into the whole family.

```
ID   E-mail              Phone          Comment
---- ------------------- -------------- ------------------------------
0    tom@email.com       +44 111 111    First row
1    tommy@email.com     +44 111 111    Same phone, different e-mail
2    thomas@email.com    +44 111 111    Same phone, different e-mail
3    thomas@email.com    +44 222 222    Same e-mail, different phone
4    sandra@email.com    +44 222 222    Same phone, different e-mail
5    sandra@email.com    +44 333 333    Same e-mail, different phone
```

As [ypercube](https://stackoverflow.com/users/344949/ypercube) said I will probably need a recursion to count all of these *unique customers*.

*Example 2*: Here is the example of what I want to do.
Is it possible to get *count of unique customers* without using recursion for instance by using cursor or something or is the recursion necessary ?

```
ID   E-mail              Phone          Comment
---- ------------------- -------------- ------------------------------
0    linsey@email.com    +44 111 111    ─┐
1    louise@email.com    +44 111 111     ├─ 1. unique customer
2    louise@email.com    +44 222 222    ─┘
---- ------------------- -------------- ------------------------------
3    steven@email.com    +44 333 333    ─┐
4    steven@email.com    +44 444 444     ├─ 2. unique customer
5    sandra@email.com    +44 444 444    ─┘
---- ------------------- -------------- ------------------------------
6    george@email.com    +44 555 555    ─── 3. unique customer
---- ------------------- -------------- ------------------------------
7    xavier@email.com    +44 666 666    ─┐
8    xavier@email.com    +44 777 777     ├─ 4. unique customer
9    xavier@email.com    +44 888 888    ─┘
---- ------------------- -------------- ------------------------------
10   robert@email.com    +44 999 999    ─┐
11   miriam@email.com    +44 999 999     ├─ 5. unique customer
12   sherry@email.com    +44 999 999    ─┘
---- ------------------- -------------- ------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Result                                  ∑ = 5 unique customers
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I've tried a query with GROUP BY but I don't know how to group the result by either first or second column. I'm looking for let's say something like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Customers
GROUP BY Email OR Phone
```

Thanks again for any suggestions

*P.S.
I really appreciate the answers for this question before the complete rephrase. Now **the answers here may not correspond to the update so please don't downvote here if you're going to do it (except the question of course :)**. I completely rewrote this post.

Thanks and sorry for my wrong start.*

Comment: Try searching for `OVER` and `PARTITION BY` or `window functions`

Comment: Why does George have a count of 3 and why does his Id go from 5 to 7

Comment: Maybe it's not clear from my question, but I'm looking only for such kind of a distinct count of unique customers. I'll update my question, so sorry for participants and thanks for the effort.

Comment: @Conrad Frix - because George and Thomas has the same phone and Thomas and Thomas has the same name (actually e-mail). So this would in the real life mean that George and Thomas are e.g. married `:)` and they have common phone so I'm counting them as one unique customer by same name or same phone.

Comment: @Conrad Frix - about that ID sorry it was a typo; I've corrected it now

Comment: @Conrad: I think what he really wants needs recursion, based on grouping both over `Phone` and `Name`. See what he commented in my answer.

Comment: @ypercube - exactly; I need a distinct count for a top level recursion nodes. I don't get it's a recursion when I was analyzing this thing. Now I'm looking around here for possibilities, so I would rather delete this question than its complete rephrase.

Comment: So I'm giving +1 for everyone and deleting this question. Thanks to all for the time and effort.

Comment: @daemon_x: Don't delete. You can add at the end of your question an "UPDATE", marking that you probably need a recursive query.

Comment: @daemon_x Just so you know reputation from deleted questions don't survive a rep recalc (self instigated or global).

Comment: @ypercube - thanks for the update; this will surely need a recursion. I have in my mind an idea that I will create a function like [this](http://sqlt.tripod.com/recursivity.htm) but I'm not sure how to modify it to count only the recursion root nodes (those which has no parent).

Comment: Still, I will probably rephrase the whole question because I haven't encounted with the recursion what is the most important thing in this case and it's necessary to choose a better example to be more clear. So this question will survive `:)` (because of that reputation recalc) but the answers may not correspond to it. Sorry; my fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a full solution using a recursive CTE.

```
;WITH Nodes AS
(
    SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Part, PartRank) SetId
        , [ID]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT [ID], 1 Part, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [E-mail]) PartRank
        FROM dbo.Customer
        UNION ALL
        SELECT [ID], 2, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Phone) PartRank
        FROM dbo.Customer
    ) A
),
Links AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT A.Id, B.Id LinkedId
    FROM Nodes A
    JOIN Nodes B ON B.SetId = A.SetId AND B.Id < A.Id
),
Routes AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Id, Id LinkedId
    FROM dbo.Customer

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DISTINCT Id, LinkedId
    FROM Links

    UNION ALL

    SELECT A.Id, B.LinkedId
    FROM Links A
    JOIN Routes B ON B.Id = A.LinkedId AND B.LinkedId < A.Id
),
TransitiveClosure AS
(
    SELECT Id, Id LinkedId
    FROM Links

    UNION

    SELECT LinkedId Id, LinkedId
    FROM Links

    UNION

    SELECT Id, LinkedId
    FROM Routes
),
UniqueCustomers AS
(
    SELECT Id, MIN(LinkedId) UniqueCustomerId
    FROM TransitiveClosure
    GROUP BY Id
)
SELECT A.Id, A.[E-mail], A.Phone, B.UniqueCustomerId
FROM dbo.Customer A
JOIN UniqueCustomers B ON B.Id = A.Id
```

Comment: +1 and accept; thank you; this works fine though but it's also extremely slow. Now I'm thinking about grouping in insert trigger in some separate column (this will boost the speed since I will use INT as a data type for it). Anyway congrats to your upcoming 2k :)

Comment: Thanks @daemon_x. I see you're also reaching 2k :-). You're right, it is slow. You could rewrite this as a multi-line table function. Use a table variable. Replace the recursive part with a WHILE loop, that removes superfluous duplicates on each iteration. This should reduce the explosion of temporary rows and hopefully speed things up.

Answer (score 1):

Finding groups that have only same Phone:

```
SELECT
    ID
  , Name
  , Phone
  , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Phone) AS GroupPhone
FROM 
    MyTable
ORDER BY
    GroupPhone
  , ID
```

---

Finding groups that have only same Name:

```
SELECT
    ID
  , Name
  , Phone
  , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Name) AS GroupName
FROM 
    MyTable
ORDER BY
    GroupName
  , ID
```

---

Now, for the (complex) query you describe, let's say we have a table like this instead:

```
ID   Name          Phone
---- ------------- -------------
0    Kate          +44 333 333
1    Sandra        +44 000 000
2    Thomas        +44 222 222
3    Robert        +44 000 000
4    Thomas        +44 444 444
5    George        +44 222 222
6    Kate          +44 000 000
7    Robert        +44 444 444
--------------------------------
```

**Should all these be in one group?** As they all share name or phone with someone else, forming a "chain" of relative persons:

```
0-6   same name
6-1-3 same phone
3-7   same name
7-4   same-phone
4-2   same name
2-5   bame phone
```

Comment: yes, exactly; the table you've mentioned might return count = 1 and as you said I would like to build a `chain`. In real life the name is e-mail which is unique for anybody in the world but you can have 2 phone numbers with the same e-mail or same phone with different e-mails. I feel this it be a very complicated query.

Comment: It's complicated, yes. It will need recursion but I'm sure someone will find a way to write it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best solution, but here it is:

```
SELECT
  MyTable.ID, MyTable.Name, MyTable.Phone,
  CASE WHEN N.No = 1 AND P.No = 1 THEN 1
       WHEN N.No = 1 AND P.No > 1 THEN 2
       WHEN N.No > 1 OR P.No > 1  THEN 3
  END as GroupRes
FROM
  MyTable 
  JOIN (SELECT Name, count(Name) No FROM MyTable GROUP BY Name) N on MyTable.Name = N.Name
  JOIN (SELECT Phone, count(Phone) No FROM MyTable GROUP BY Phone) P on MyTable.Phone = P.Phone
```

The problem is that here are some joins made on varchars and could end up in increasing execution time.

Comment: ID: 7, Name: George ends up with a count of 2 but this is probably correct. You should note that you're missing `Group by` on your inline views and it probably wouldn't hurt to add `Order by GroupRes`

Comment: @Conrad Frix: Ups, forgot to put the GROUP BY. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the dataset in the example you could write something like this:

```
;WITH Temp AS (
    SELECT Name, Phone,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Name) AS NameGroup,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Phone) AS PhoneGroup
    FROM MyTable)
SELECT MAX(Phone), MAX(Name), COUNT(*)
FROM Temp
GROUP BY NameGroup, PhoneGroup
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
SELECT p.LastName, P.FirstName, P.HomePhone,
CASE 
    WHEN ph.PhoneCount=1 THEN       
        CASE 
            WHEN n.NameCount=1 THEN 'unique name and phone'
            ELSE 'common name'
        END

    ELSE        
        CASE 
            WHEN n.NameCount=1 THEN 'common phone'
            ELSE 'common phone and name'        
        END             
END
FROM Contacts p
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT HomePhone, count(LastName) as PhoneCount
FROM Contacts
GROUP BY HomePhone) ph ON ph.HomePhone = p.HomePhone

INNER JOIN 
(SELECT FirstName, count(LastName) as NameCount
FROM Contacts
GROUP BY FirstName) n ON n.FirstName = p.FirstName


LastN       FirstN  Phone       Comment
Hoover      Brenda  8138282334  unique name and phone
Washington  Brian   9044563211  common name
Roosevelt   Brian   7737653279  common name
Reagan      Charles 7734567869  unique name and phone
```