# Is there a way to group accounts together that match on different fields, and group whatever those accounts group onto?

Tags: sql, ssms

I need to create a new unique id for companies which would have multiple accounts with us. I have company names, but I know there are typos that would throw the data off. I have other unique fields I'd like to work with to group data together when this is the case.

I have a couple hundred thousand accounts that have at least the given information
company name, phone, and e-mail. 
In the case that company name differs between two accounts, but the accounts have a match on any other field, I'd like SQL to give it the same unique ID (suspected typo). Further in the case that an additional account matches on account 2's company name, but matches on no other field for anything else I'd like it to receive the same unique ID as the previous two (suspected recurring typo).

[SQL query like GROUP BY with OR condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280629/sql-query-like-group-by-with-or-condition)

This is similar to what I'm trying to do except I need to add a third field. However I noticed that after trying to use the suggested answer (below) it would only group some companies together based off of the number of their ID. This seems to be because it added the b.linkedId < a.id filter to stop it from looping forever. The article is from 8 years ago, but I believe nobody accurately solved that user's problem either. It might be useful code to get closer however.

```
WITH Nodes AS
(
    SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Part, PartRank) SetId
        , [ID]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT [ID], 1 Part, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [E-mail]) PartRank
        FROM dbo.Customer
        UNION ALL
        SELECT [ID], 2, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Phone) PartRank
        FROM dbo.Customer
    ) A
),
Links AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT A.Id, B.Id LinkedId
    FROM Nodes A
    JOIN Nodes B ON B.SetId = A.SetId AND B.Id < A.Id
),
Routes AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Id, Id LinkedId
    FROM dbo.Customer

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DISTINCT Id, LinkedId
    FROM Links

    UNION ALL

    SELECT A.Id, B.LinkedId
    FROM Links A
    JOIN Routes B ON B.Id = A.LinkedId AND B.LinkedId < A.Id
),
TransitiveClosure AS
(
    SELECT Id, Id LinkedId
    FROM Links

    UNION

    SELECT LinkedId Id, LinkedId
    FROM Links

    UNION

    SELECT Id, LinkedId
    FROM Routes
),
UniqueCustomers AS
(
    SELECT Id, MIN(LinkedId) UniqueCustomerId
    FROM TransitiveClosure
    GROUP BY Id
)
SELECT A.Id, A.[E-mail], A.Phone, B.UniqueCustomerId
FROM dbo.Customer A
JOIN UniqueCustomers B ON B.Id = A.Id
```

The below code is what I've used to show why the above code doesn't work as intended. ID is the unique identifier for each account, Email is one field to aggregate on, and phone is another. Everything I've commented out was me attempting to add in Company_Name to the query, but that is when I realized there is a problem. If I can get past grouping on Phone and email, the next step to this problem would be getting it to work with company name as well.

```
With Customers AS 
(
    Select 1 as [ID]
            ,'John@G.com' as [E-mail]
            ,'111-111-1111' as [Phone]
            --,'Mcdonaldss' as [Company_Name]
    union all 
    Select 0, 'Harry@g.com', '121-212-1212'--,'Mmcdonalds'
    union all
    Select 2, 'Grant@g.com', '111-111-1111'--, 'Mcdonallds'    
    union all
    Select 3, 'John@G.com', '222-222-2222'--, 'Mcdonnalds'    
    union all
    select 4, 'Harry@g.com', '222-222-2222'--, 'Mccdonalds'    
    union all 
    Select 5, 'Jack@g.com', '444-444-4444'--, 'Wendys'     
            --union all
            --Select 10, 'Sarah@g.com', '888-888-8888', 'Mcdonald'    
            --union all 
            --Select 9, 'Sarah@g.com', '999-999-9999', 'Mcdoonalds'     
            --union all
            --Select 8, 'Jessy@g.com', '999-999-9999', 'Mcds'     
            --Union all
            --Select 7, 'Jessy@g.com', '777-777-7777', 'Mcdanalds'     
            --Union all
            --Select 6, 7, '777-777-7777', 'Mcdonolds'    
            --Union all
            --Select 11, 8, '222-222-2222', 'Mcds'
),
 Nodes AS
(
    SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Part, PartRank) SetId
        , [ID]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT c.[ID], '1 email' Part, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [E-mail]) PartRank
        FROM Customers as [c]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT c.[ID], '2 phone', DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Phone) PartRank
        FROM Customers as [c]
        --union all
        --SELECT c.[ID], '3 Compnay_Name', DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Next_level) PartRank
  --      FROM #Customer as [c]
    ) A
),
Links AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT A.Id, B.Id LinkedId
    FROM Nodes A
    JOIN Nodes B ON B.SetId = A.SetId AND B.Id < A.Id
)
--Select * from links
,
roads AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Id, Id LinkedId
    FROM Customers as [c]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DISTINCT Id, LinkedId
    FROM links

    UNION ALL

    SELECT A.Id, B.LinkedId
    FROM Links A
    JOIN Roads B ON B.Id = A.LinkedId AND B.LinkedId < A.Id
)
--Select * from Roads
,
TransitiveClosure AS
(
    SELECT Id, Id LinkedId
    FROM Links

    UNION

    SELECT LinkedId Id, LinkedId
    FROM Links

    UNION

    SELECT Id, LinkedId
    FROM roads
)

--Select * from TransitiveClosure
,
UniqueCustomers AS
(
    SELECT Id, MIN(LinkedId) UniqueCustomerId
    FROM TransitiveClosure
    GROUP BY Id
)
SELECT A.Id, A.[E-mail], A.Phone, dense_rank() over (order by B.UniqueCustomerId) as [Company_no]
FROM Customers A
JOIN UniqueCustomers B ON B.Id = A.Id
```

In this example I'd like ID 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4 all have the same Company_no. Yet because ID 0 is below ID 1, ID 1 does not link to ID 0. This means anything linking to ID 1 doesn't link to ID 0 either and it splits the results. ID 5 is my control. It shouldn't be aggregated with anything. 
All the other accounts that are commented out would then match back as well to Mcdonalds when Company Name is added in, but that second part I should be able to solve after being able to join two fields accurately.

Desired output

```
ID   E-mail              Phone          Unique ID
---- ------------------- -------------- ------------------------------
0    Harry@g.com        121-212-1212    ─┐
1    John@G.com         111-111-1111     | 
2    Grant@g.com        111-111-1111     ├─ 1 (Mcdonalds)
3    John@G.com         222-222-2222     |
4    Harry@g.com        222-222-2222    ─┘
---- ------------------- -------------- ------------------------------
5    Jack@g.com         444-444-4444    ─── 2 (Wendys)
```

**Update**
I've managed to make the code do what I want by removing the offending filter mentioned above, increasing the Max Recursion, and adding in a limit to the amount of loops in the roads section as shown below. This gives the desired output and works for all three fields, however, when going from 12 rows to 104,000 .... it isn't a practical solution. It turned 1000 records into a million and wasn't even finished. Any tips to prevent pointless looping, or tackling this grouping differently?

Current Code

```
With Customers AS 
(
    Select 1 as [ID]
            ,'John@G.com' as [E-mail]
            ,'111-111-1111' as [Phone]
            ,'Mcdonaldss' as [Company_Name]
    union all 
    Select 0, 'Harry@g.com', '121-212-1212','Mmcdonalds'
    union all
    Select 2, 'Grant@g.com', '111-111-1111', 'Mcdonallds'    
    union all
    Select 3, 'John@G.com', '222-222-2222', 'Mcdonnalds'    
    union all
    select 4, 'Harry@g.com', '222-222-2222', 'Mccdonalds'    
    union all 
    Select 5, 'Jack@g.com', '444-444-4444', 'Wendys'     
    union all
    Select 10, 'Sarah@g.com', '888-888-8888', 'Mcdonald'    
    union all  
    Select 9, 'Sarah@g.com', '999-999-9999', 'Mcdoonalds'     
    union all
    Select 8, 'Jessy@g.com', '999-999-9999', 'Mcds'     
    Union all
    Select 7, 'Jessy@g.com', '777-777-7777', 'Mcdanalds'     
    Union all
    Select 6, 'Mark@g.com', '777-777-7777', 'Mcdonolds'    
    Union all
    Select 11, 'Carol@g.com', '222-222-2222', 'Mcds'
    Union all
    Select 12, 'carol@g.com', '101-010-1010','Mcdooonalds'
),
 Nodes AS
(
    SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Part, PartRank) SetId
        , [ID]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT c.[ID], '1 email' Part, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [E-mail]) PartRank
        FROM Customers as [c]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT c.[ID], '2 phone', DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Phone) PartRank
        FROM Customers as [c]
        union all
        SELECT c.[ID], '3 Company_Name', DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Company_Name) PartRank
        FROM Customers as [c]
    ) A
),
Links AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT A.Id, B.Id LinkedId
    FROM Nodes A
    JOIN Nodes B ON B.SetId = A.SetId AND B.Id <> A.Id
)
--Select * from links
,
roads AS
(

    SELECT DISTINCT Id, Id LinkedId, 0 as [count]
    FROM Customers as [c]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DISTINCT Id, LinkedId, '0'
    FROM links

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
     A.Id, B.LinkedId, B.[count]+1
    FROM Links A
    JOIN Roads B ON B.Id = A.LinkedId AND B.LinkedId <> A.Id
    Where b.[count] <= 10

)
--Select * from Roads
,
TransitiveClosure AS
(
    SELECT Id, Id LinkedId
    FROM Links

    UNION

    SELECT LinkedId Id, LinkedId
    FROM Links

    UNION

    SELECT Id, LinkedId
    FROM roads
)

--Select * from TransitiveClosure
,
UniqueCustomers AS
(
    SELECT Id, MIN(LinkedId) UniqueCustomerId
    FROM TransitiveClosure
    GROUP BY Id
)
SELECT A.Id, A.[E-mail], A.Phone, A.company_Name, dense_rank() over (order by B.UniqueCustomerId) as [Company_no]
FROM Customers A
JOIN UniqueCustomers B ON B.Id = A.Id
option (maxrecursion 32767)
```

Comment: Why not clean the data first, then use a simple `GROUP BY`? It might seem prohibitive to manually clean up every incorrect element, but it's going to be really difficult to write code that can automatically account for every potential typo out there.

Comment: Looking through a 100,000 accounts to manually check for typos seems unrealistic. One of my hopes for this query was that it would group these companies together clearly highlighting where typos might exist for easy Data Cleanup. Especially for cases where the first letter may have been typed differently or the company name has changed, so it wouldn't come up easily in an order by or something.

Comment: That assumes that you're actually looking line-by-line at the table. Instead, you should by querying to see what company names/phone numbers don't match a sanitized list. It also assumes that every single company name has been mistyped in a different way, which is unlikely. It also ignores that once the initial cleanup is done, you never have to do it again so long as you sanitize your going forward. As I mentioned, it's going to be really difficult to write code that accounts for all typos in all situations. I would personally not try to solve this problem this way.

Comment: Maybe. I thought there might be a way for SQL to make this easier, by matching on other fields that would suggest they are a match, but if that isn't the case, manual data cleanup would be the backup option. The problem is if the data is typed wrong when input, that wrong input is used everywhere. So the list I'm looking at is already the most sanitized list we have. There isn't a more clean list that I can compare to (If I understood what you meant properly). Either way If SQL can't help of course I could always aggregate on the different fields individually and try to cleanup that way.