# Group by any shared value in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Normally, group-by works by grouping together unique keys from the table. However, I want to group rows together if they share any of the same values.

Let's say I want to group by A, B, C in this table...

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 1 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 | 8 |

I would like to group (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 4), (2, 2, 8) together, because they each share at least one column value with another element in the group.

(4, 5, 6) though doesn't share any values with any of the other elements, so it would be its own group.

So the expected output would be two groups:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 8 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 | 4 |

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |

Any ideas on how I can achieve this behavior (ideally in a somewhat efficient way because I have ~1 million rows in my pandas DataFrame)?

This question asks for the same thing but is SQL specific:
[SQL query like GROUP BY with OR condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280629/sql-query-like-group-by-with-or-condition)

Comment: kindly post your expected output. You could also share what you have tried

Comment: Well, I'm thinking about using df.groupby with a custom function for "by," or by grouping by one column at a time, then recursively combining the groups that share other values somehow @sammywemmy. I updated the post with my expected output in tabular format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is not the most beautiful solution, but here we go. First we `melt` the original dataframe, so that all the row values become part of one single column. Also, by using `reset_index` and `set_index` we create a new `index` that keeps track of the original row where each value came from.

```
df_melt = (df.reset_index()
             .melt(id_vars='index')
             .set_index('index'))
```

So far we have the following dataframe:

```
      variable  value
index                
0            A      1
1            A      4
2            A      1
3            A      2
0            B      2
1            B      5
2            B      3
3            B      2
0            C      3
1            C      6
2            C      4
3            C      8
```

Now we use a `groupby` to filter the rows of the original dataframe that have the same values. Since we need to keep track of the values' column as well, we do the following `groupby`:

```
grouped = df_melt.groupby(['variable', 'value']).groups
```

Which gives us:

```
# print(grouped)
{('A', 1): [0, 2], ('A', 2): [3], ('A', 4): [1], 
 ('B', 2): [0, 3], ('B', 3): [2], ('B', 5): [1], 
 ('C', 3): [0], ('C', 4): [2], ('C', 6): [1], ('C', 8): [3]}
```

Then we create a dictionary that summarizes the groups per column:

```
groups_per_col = {
    col: [set(value) for key, value in grouped.items() if key[0] == col] for col in cols
}
# {'A': [{0, 2}, {3}, {1}], 'B': [{0, 3}, {2}, {1}], 'C': [{0}, {2}, {1}, {3}]}
```

And finally we reach the real problem, which is to find all independent sets of rows among all columns.

```
final_groups = []
for col in groups_per_col:
    my_groups = groups_per_col[col]

    for g in my_groups:
        for i, aux in enumerate(final_groups):
            if len(aux.intersection(g)) > 0:
                final_groups[i] = aux.union(g)
                break
        else:
            final_groups.append(g)

    aux_groups = []
    while True:
        for g in final_groups:
            for i, aux in enumerate(aux_groups):
                if len(aux.intersection(g)) > 0:
                    aux_groups[i] = aux.union(g)
                    break
            else:
                aux_groups.append(g)
        if len(aux_groups) == len(final_groups):
            break
        else:
            final_groups = aux_groups[:]
            aux_groups = []
```

This may take time depending on the number of rows (which is bad in your case, with 1 million rows) but also depending on the number of the possible values inside your df. If you have values within from 0 to 100, for example, the following code runs in about 20 seconds (in my humble laptop), but if there are 1000 possible values, this time raises to 2 minutes. This code isn't perfect in terms of efficiency, but at least it's a place to start.

The code output is `final_groups`, which gives us a list of sets, where every set contains the rows belonging to the same group:

```
[{0, 2, 3}, {1}]
```

It's up to you what to do with this groups. You can, for example, create a new column in your dataframe with an identifier, such as:

```
df['Group'] = ['G{}'.format(
              [index in group for group in final_groups].index(True)) 
              for index in df.index]
```

Which results in the following dataframe:

```
   A  B  C Group
0  1  2  3    G0
1  4  5  6    G1
2  1  3  4    G0
3  2  2  8    G0
```

Anyone is invited to suggest improvements. Hope this is useful for you somehow!

Comment: This is extremely helpful, I ended up adopting something very similar to this. Thank you for your guidance!

Answer (score 0):

Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A ': {0: 1, 1: 4, 2: 1, 3: 2},
 'B ': {0: 2, 1: 5, 2: 3, 3: 2},
 'C': {0: 3, 1: 6, 2: 4, 3: 8}})
```

df:

```
   A   B   C
0   1   2  3
1   4   5  6
2   1   3  4
3   2   2  8
```

```
df = df.T
df.loc["Groups"] = df.apply(lambda xx:  xx.isin(df.drop(columns=xx.name)).any()).replace({True : 'G1', False : 'G2'}).to_list()
```

df.T:

```
  A  B   C Groups
0  1  2  3     G1
1  4  5  6     G2
2  1  3  4     G1
3  2  2  8     G1
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm a bit confused though, this seems to separate the rows into:
G1 = rows that are "connected to any other row"
G2 = rows that aren't connected to any other row

Sorry if it wasn't clear, but I was looking for something which bundles together rows that have shared values. Depending on the data, there could be many different groups.