# Pandas Grouby with OR condition

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following data set.

| i_id | g_id | s_id | p_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1001 | 1001 |  |
| 1002 | 1001 | 1001 |  |
| 1003 | 1001 | 1001 | 1003 |
| 1004 | 1004 | 1001 | 1003 |
| 1005 | 1004 | 1001 | 1003 |
| 1006 | 1004 |  | 1003 |
| 1007 | 1007 | 1007 | 1003 |
| 1008 | 1007 | 1007 | 1003 |
| 1009 | 1009 | 1007 |  |
| 1010 | 1010 | 1007 |  |

I would like to create groups where if either column has a common value, they should be grouped together. If there is a blank, then it should ignore that for grouping purposes and just preserve the grouping based on the other columns. Also key would be the smallest "i_id" of that particular group.

| i_id | g_id | s_id | p_id | Key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1001 | 1001 |  | 1001 |
| 1002 | 1001 | 1001 |  | 1001 |
| 1003 | 1001 | 1001 | 1003 | 1001 |
| 1004 | 1004 | 1001 | 1003 | 1001 |
| 1005 | 1004 | 1001 | 1003 | 1001 |
| 1006 | 1004 |  | 1003 | 1001 |
| 1007 | 1007 | 1007 | 1003 | 1001 |
| 1008 | 1007 | 1007 | 1003 | 1001 |
| 1009 | 1009 | 1007 |  | 1001 |
| 1010 | 1010 | 1007 |  | 1001 |
| 1011 | 1011 | 1011 | 1011 | 1011 |
| 1012 | 1012 | 1012 | 1012 | 1012 |
| 1013 | 1013 | 1013 | 1013 | 1013 |
| 1014 | 1014 | 1014 | 1014 | 1014 |

So here, there are 5 groups namely, 1001, 1011, 1012, 1013 and 1014

This is very similar to another question I found here, please find the link below.

[SQL query like GROUP BY with OR condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280629/sql-query-like-group-by-with-or-condition)

I would like to know if there is any way to do this in pandas or any other solution is also appreciated.

Comment: Hi! It is not clear how to create `Key` column. For example, why the 6th row has `1001` as key?

Comment: the 6th row has p_id as 1003, notice that the 3rd row also has the same p_id and the g_id and s_id for third row is 1001, so by that link of 1003, they are grouped together with 1001 as key since its the smallest i_id in that group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `networkx` with [`connected_components`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_components.html) for dictionary created by minimal common values and then mapping to new column:

```
import networkx as nx

df1 = (df.melt('i_id')
        .dropna(subset=['value'])
        .groupby('i_id', as_index=False)['value'].min())
print (df1)
    i_id value
0   1001  1001
1   1002  1001
2   1003  1001
3   1004  1001
4   1005  1001
5   1006  1003
6   1007  1003
7   1008  1003
8   1009  1007
9   1010  1007
10  1011  1011
11  1012  1012
12  1013  1013
13  1014  1014

# Create the graph from the dataframe
g = nx.Graph()
g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df1,'i_id','value')

connected_components = nx.connected_components(g)
# print (list(connected_components))

d = {y: min(x) for x in connected_components for y in x}
df['Key'] = df['i_id'].map(d)
```

---

```
print (df)
    i_id  g_id  s_id  p_id   Key
0   1001  1001  1001   NaN  1001
1   1002  1001  1001   NaN  1001
2   1003  1001  1001  1003  1001
3   1004  1004  1001  1003  1001
4   1005  1004  1001  1003  1001
5   1006  1004   NaN  1003  1001
6   1007  1007  1007  1003  1001
7   1008  1007  1007  1003  1001
8   1009  1009  1007   NaN  1001
9   1010  1010  1007   NaN  1001
10  1011  1011  1011  1011  1011
11  1012  1012  1012  1012  1012
12  1013  1013  1013  1013  1013
13  1014  1014  1014  1014  1014
```

Comment: so i do not need the min value of all columns. Let me explain the real life scenario. g_id, s_id and p_id are groupings done by 3 different people based on their own criteria. The idea is to combine all the 3 groupings and create a common family key. please check this link, it is a similar requirement: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280629/sql-query-like-group-by-with-or-condition

Comment: @Vwake - Yo uare right, answer was edited

Comment: Thank you for this! :)