# How do I create groups in a dataframe based on different 'or' conditions? And keep track of how many of those conditions match?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Very similar to this question in SQL: [SQL query like GROUP BY with OR condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280629/sql-query-like-group-by-with-or-condition)

I'm looking to group some data together based on certain 'or' conditions. I want people grouped together if they meet at least one of the four criteria, and I'd also like to give each person a score for how well-placed they are in the group (e.g., how many of the four criteria they meet).

I don't really grasp what can be fully done with the pandas groupby so I can only do each criteria separately. I'm not sure how to join each 'OR' criteria, as well as create the composite scorings and namings of the groups (I'm assuming I'd have to code the group names in instead of using a column field name since people can be grouped together based on different criteria they fit).

**Grouping criteria:**

1. If a person has the same address (address line 1 + address line 2) as someone else, they're grouped together.
2. If a person has the same address line 1 (address line 2 not necessary) and they have the same last name as someone else, then they're grouped together.
3. If a person has the same phone number as someone else, they're grouped together.
4. If a person has the same account number as someone else, they're grouped together.

Then a "strength" score for how well-placed they are with someone else in the group, based on how many of the above criteria they fit. Score should be the highest score when compared any person in the same group. If person A matches all addresses, last names, phone numbers, and account numbers as person B, both of their scores would be 4; whereas person C with only a matching phone number and account number would fall into the same group, but with a score of 2. If someone is in a group by themselves, then their score is 0.

Please assume that people don't end up in one giant convoluted group lol.

**Data**

```
data = {'first_name': ['Jane', 'Bob', 'Jim', 'Karen', 'Bob', 'Timmy', 'Kim', 'Tom'],
        'last_name': ['Doe', 'Doe', 'Doe', 'Smith', 'Smith', 'Smith', 'McDonald', 'McDonald'],
        'address_1': ['123 Adams St', '123 Adams St', '123 Adams St', '234 Adams St', '8377 Smith Ave', '8377 Smith Ave', '2100 Smith St', '2100 Smith St'],
        'address_2': ['', '', '#100', 'Apt 10', 'Apt C', '', '', ''],
        'phone_num': [123456, 123654, 548978, 693817, 837263, 732612, 456871, 254803],
        'account_num': ['abcdex', 'abcdex', 'xwysa', 'lmnop', 'rstuv', 'wqoeu', 'xwysa', 'hijkl']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['first_name', 'last_name', 'address_1', 'address_2', 'phone_num', 'account_num'])
```

| first_name | last_name | address_1 | address_2 | phone_num | account_num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jane | Doe | 123 Adams St |  | 123456 | abcdex |
| Bob | Doe | 123 Adams St |  | 123654 | abcdex |
| Jim | Doe | 123 Adams St | #100 | 548978 | xwysa |
| Karen | Smith | 234 Adams St | Apt 10 | 693817 | lmnop |
| Bob | Smith | 8377 Smith Ave | Apt C | 837263 | rstuv |
| Timmy | Smith | 8377 Smith Ave |  | 732612 | wqoeu |
| Kim | McDonald | 2100 Smith St |  | 456871 | xwysa |
| Tom | McDonald | 2100 Smith St |  | 254803 | hijkl |

**Desired output:**

| first_name | last_name | address_1 | address_2 | phone_num | account_num | group | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jane | Doe | 123 Adams St |  | 123456 | abcdex | group1 | 3 |
| Bob | Doe | 123 Adams St |  | 123654 | abcdex | group1 | 3 |
| Jim | Doe | 123 Adams St | #100 | 548978 | xwysa | group1 | 1 |
| Karen | Smith | 234 Adams St | Apt 10 | 693817 | lmnop | group2 | 0 |
| Bob | Smith | 8377 Smith Ave | Apt C | 837263 | rstuv | group3 | 1 |
| Timmy | Smith | 8377 Smith Ave |  | 732612 | wqoeu | group3 | 1 |
| Kim | McDonald | 2100 Smith St |  | 456871 | xwysa | group1 | 2 |
| Tom | McDonald | 2100 Smith St |  | 254803 | hijkl | group1 | 2 |

Kim and Tom McDonald join group1 since Kim's account_num is the same as Jim's, and Tom is in the same group as Kim. Both their scores are 2 since they have matching addresses and address1+last name with each other, and that's a higher score than Kim's matching criteria with Jim (only 1 for matching account_num).

**Some code I've tried:**
I've tried to understand some of the other pandas groupby questions here, but they don't seem to apply to grouping by 'OR' conditions. So I'm really not sure how to go about it, below is what I have for one criteria.

```
df['criteria1'] = df['address_1'] + df['address_2'].fillna('NULL')
df['criteria2'] = df['address_1'] + df['last_name']

df['score_crit1'] = df.groupby('criteria1').cumcount()
df['score_crit1'] = df.groupby('criteria1')['score_crit1'].transform('max')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you can approach your problem like a graph with [networkx](/questions/tagged/networkx) :

```
tmp = (df.assign(name= lambda x: x.pop("first_name")
            .str.cat(x.pop("last_name"), sep=" "))
        .melt(ignore_index=False, id_vars=["name"])
        .fillna("").drop(columns="variable")
        .query("value != ''").sort_index(ignore_index=True))
```

---

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(tmp, source="name", target="value")

d = {n: f"group{i}" for i, s in enumerate(
    nx.connected_components(G), 1) for n in s if n in list(tmp["name"])}

out = df.join(df["first_name"].str.cat(
    df["last_name"], sep=" ").map(d).rename("group"))
       
out["score"] = (out.groupby(["group", "last_name"], group_keys=False)
             [['address_1', 'address_2', 'phone_num', 'account_num']].apply(
            lambda g: g.apply(lambda s: s.duplicated(keep=False)).sum(axis=1)))
```

Output :

```
print(out)

  first_name last_name       address_1 address_2  phone_num account_num   group  score
0       Jane       Doe    123 Adams St               123456      abcdex  group1      3
1        Bob       Doe    123 Adams St               123654      abcdex  group1      3
2        Jim       Doe    123 Adams St      #100     548978       xwysa  group1      1
3      Karen     Smith    234 Adams St    Apt 10     693817       lmnop  group2      0
4        Bob     Smith  8377 Smith Ave     Apt C     837263       rstuv  group3      1
5      Timmy     Smith  8377 Smith Ave               732612       wqoeu  group3      1
6        Kim  McDonald   2100 Smith St               456871       xwysa  group1      2
7        Tom  McDonald   2100 Smith St               254803       hijkl  group1      2

[8 rows x 8 columns]
```

[image]

Comment: You're absolutely correct, Karen Smith's number should've been different, sorry about that, just edited to fix! 
Trying to fully understand your code since this is my first time seeing networkx, this seems like the way to go, thank you! But when I run the score portion of the code, I end up with an error, "Series.name must be a hashable type."

Comment: @Timeless, I had seen this question and was busy at the time, I had a much similar logic in mind, great answer ;)

Comment: @evhol, `pip install -U pandas` should fix the error. I'm using the latest `2.1.2`.

Comment: @mozway, I discovered `networkx` thanks to you. You're `#1` when it comes to takling graph probs ;)

Comment: Thanks so much @Timeless, worked flawlessly after updating my pandas! Will come back to upvote your answer once I have enough reputation points haha